# Why viewBinding makes XML root full screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I am wondering why adding `viewBinding` to my app, makes the XML root display in full screen when running the app. The root doesn't display in full screen in the designer view inside Android Studio.

Due to the root displaying in full screen, I had to add `android:gravity="center"` to vertically align the children in the center. While I don't think this should be a problem, I'm still interested in knowing why this is the case.

[image]

I have the following code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/roll_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/roll"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
package com.example.diceroller

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.diceroller.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.rollButton.text = "testBind"
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think that when You execute this `setContentView(binding.root)` You are setting a linear layout as fullscreen.

[setContentView Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setContentView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))

> Set the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed directly into the activity's view hierarchy. It can itself be a complex view hierarchy. When calling this method, the layout parameters of the specified view are ignored. **Both the `width` and the `height` of the view are set by default to `ViewGroup.LayoutParams#MATCH_PARENT`. To use your own layout parameters, invoke `setContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)` instead.**

To do make it looks like in the preview You can write this code.
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/roll_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Roll" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.rollButton.text = "Test Roll"
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

---

*Tip: To convert fast Your layout to data binding layout use: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> ➡ `Convert to data binding layout`*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I appreciate it. Although I still have some problems and questions.

1. Do you have any idea why setContentView would ignore the layout parameters?
2. I use viewBinding, thus the shortcut to convert my layout isn't available.
3. When I edit my layout myself, I get the following error (which I bet is due to using viewBinding instead of dataBinding); `Cannot access 'no_name_in_PSI_3d19d79d_1ba9_4cd0_b7f5_b46aa3cd5d40' which is a supertype of 'com.example.diceroller.databinding.ActivityMainBinding'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that You use ViewBinding, not DataBinding. But I think `setContentView` with only one parameter ignores view layout parameters because this is just how this function works: `When calling this method, the layout parameters of the specified view are ignored.`. If You want to use Your params You have to add this as the second parameter. but I think Your layout will be placed at the top of the screen not in the center.